# sharePoint designer 2013 installtion on windows server 2008 standard

Tags: sharepoint

I try to  install sharePoint designer 2013 on windows server 2008 standard but it fails if anybody have know about the any version of sharepoint designer works on windows server 2008 standard operating system

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: program require windows 7 or windows server 2008 r2 os..

Comment: Well and you windows server 2008 you have?

Comment: ya but my os is windows server 2008 standard is not r2,so is any sharepoint designer 2013 version for for server 2008 standard?

Comment: my main problem is ,i want to import sharepoint list template in another server environment but my template contains the custom item form i able to import list but the list item custom form can not work it gives webpart error

Comment: did you see the answer? or even the edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the main Question about if is there a version to Windows Server 2008 Standar

The answer, sadly its **not**

This is the compatible version to SharePoint

```
Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012
```

About the Second question, take a look [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112089/how-to-use-imported-list-template).